# Matlab error in conditional if statement: Attempt to reference field of non-structure array

Tags: matlab

Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

```
Error in ==> Project_3 at 23.             
if (alpha>=alpha_1 .and. alpha<=alpha_2)   %region from a to b
```

My original code:

```
for alpha=-90:1:90
    dum=dum+1

    if (alpha>=alpha_1 .and. alpha<=alpha_2)   %region from a to b

        [A] =gradient_linear_equation(alpha_1,alpha_2,cl_1,cl_2);
        [B] =constant_linear_equation(A,alpha_1,cl_1);
        [y] =linear_equation(A,alpha,B)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean `&` or `&&`, not `.and.`. I believe `.and.` is Fortran syntax, yes?

The relevant documentation for logical operators in Matlab is [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorselementwise.html).

By the way, I can see how that error message could throw you onto the wrong trail. Matlab uses `.` to access the fields of a structure, eg, `S.alpha = 1` allocates a `1` to the field `alpha` in the structure `S`. Hence it probably thought you were trying to reference the `and` field in structure `alpha_1` - even though `alpha_1` is a numeric matrix - hence the error.

Comment: @CheeYongChong The best thanks is to mark the question answered by clicking the tick mark next to my response. Cheers, glad I could help.